# What is the EntityLogicalName for activities in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: node.js, http, dynamics-crm

I've been able to successfully fetch items like leads, opportunities, and contacts from the dynamics API, but I've been unable to figure out how to fetch any kind of activity objects. I'm making a request that looks like this:

```
POST http://myAddress/myDomain/RetrieveMultiple

**headers**
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: our user agent

**json**
{
  "Credential": {
    "Domain": "thedomain",
    "UserId": "theuserid",
    "Password": "thepass",
    "Version": "2016",
    "ConnectionType": "1"
  },
  "EntityLogicalName": "contact",
  "DateCriteria": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "DateFilterName": "modifiedon",
  "Operator": ">=",
  "Order": "asc",
  "MaxItems": 100,
  "pageNumber": 1
}
```

When I change the EntityLogicalName to "activitypointer", "task", "appointment", and anything else I can think of I get back an error that says "Invalid Entity name"

Answer (score 0):

Activities is an abstract entity, therefore you'll need to query the concrete ones like:

"email", "phonecall", "task", etc...

Comment: Unfortunately whenever I request task objects I still get the same Invalid Entity Name error (and also the same for email, etc).